# Having trouble loading custom view from xib in another xib

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xib, loadnibnamed

Apologies because I see people have asked questions like this before. However, I haven't had much luck following the instructions.  I'm interested in creating a custom view with a xib file and reusing it in another view controller's xib file.

Existing Posts:

[Using xib object inside another xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095359/using-xib-object-inside-another-xib)

[How to use a xib and a UIView subclass together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071738/how-to-use-a-xib-and-a-uiview-subclass-together)

I have already:

- Created a custom xib file (let's call it CustomView.xib), and corresponding .h and .m class files
- Set the File's Owner of the xib file to CustomView
- Created a top level UIView with other views as children (UILabel's etc)

  - NOTE this has a child UIView which is a custom view written in code as well
- Wired up the IBOutlets
- Created a ViewController.xib file
- Added a UIView, set the class to CustomView and also wired that up

This results in a blank view showing up when I build the application.

I then tried what one of the above posts said to do which was override CustomView's initWithDecoder method and adding the following:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:mainView];
```

This unfortunately was resulting in the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<UIView 0x548ff00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
```

I thought this might be because I didn't set the top level view in CustomView.xib to be of class CustomView.  So I then changed it to CustomView, and then things went into infinite recursion.  Which makes sense since it's just reloading itself over and over again.

Not sure what I missed from those previous posts, but I'd appreciate any guidance! Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that setting the File's Owner of the xib file to Custom View it's the problem. Maybe this approach helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487911/uiview-subclass-with-a-delegate-using-nib/17491977#17491977

Answer (score 1):

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<UIView 0x548ff00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
```

Reason for the above `error` normally comes due the failure of the connections in the `Interface Builder`, that is the `UIViewController` object with the corresponding objects in the implementation class. Please check your all connection in the `Interface Builder`. Also verify the file owner in the `xib` file.

I hope this will solve your problem.