# UIView Subclass with a delegate using NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to subclass a UIView using the nib. Using the following code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSArray *v = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Qus_Scale1to7View" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:[v objectAtIndex:0]];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *v = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Qus_Scale1to7View" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:[v objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

this creates the object correctly and view also displayed and when the object loads from its nib the delegate instantly becomes null and ignores any attempt to assign values to it.

Can anyone know the reason why it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subclass using a nib? Is the view in the nib that you are using a custom subclass? Please provide some more context like what is the setup inside the xib?

Comment: @Rakesh : I have some UI controls like UILabel and UIButtons etc. and i want to reuse this view in other view controllers. The problem arise when i am instantiating the view and set the delegates and some other properties the controls but nothing happened on them all controls references become NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work reusing same xib for multiple view controllers. If you want to reuse that view make a class that inherits from UIView and add the code there.

```
#import "SomeProtocol.h"

@interface MyCustomView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
    IBOutlet UIView *footerView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *updateBtn;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SomeProtocol> delegate;

@end

............

@implementation BCFirmwareView

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

+ (id)viewFromNibWithName: (NSString*)name {
    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: name owner: self options: nil];
    if (views) {
        for (UIView *aView in views) {
            if ([aView isKindOfClass: NSClassFromString(name)])
                view = aView;
        }
    }

    return view;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];

    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [[MyCustomView viewFromNibWithName: @"MyCustomView"] retain];
    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.delegate = nil;

    [headerView release];
    [footerView release];
    [updateBtn release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview: newSuperview];

    if (!newSuperview)
        return;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
}

- (IBAction)updateBtnPressed: (id)sender {
// do some stuff
}

@end
```

The next step is to open the xib in Interface Builder and set your class as the custom class  for the view, not for the File's Responder. Right click on the view and make the outlet and actions connections.

[image: change the custom class for the view]

[image: make the outlet and actions connections for the view]

Now you should be able to simply make instances of your MyCustomView in any view controller and use it. Will work from Interface Builder as well if you don't forget to change your view custom class to your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UIView with Xib and add properties to it.
Then you link the class with the xib and link the properties with the IB.

Or you can only use the

```
NSArray *v = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Qus_Scale1to7View" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *view = [v objectAtIndex:0];
```

and set your objects values using **viewWithTag:** method.

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:yourTag];
```

Let me know if this helps.