# Custom UIView for displaying a label on many ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I'm new to objective-c and it's a a newbie question.
I'm writing an app which has this custom looking label on many views. 
(edit) The label has two parts: main label that acts as a title and a smaller sublabel that has some short text. (/edit)
It seems silly to put labels manually on all of the views so I started thinking about making a custom control that would consist of two labels: `mainLabel` and `subLabel`. I'm not sure what approach is better here. Should I make a custom `UIView` or is there a better way of doing it?

If customizing `UIView` is the right way, how should I handle setting of the labels? Is creating a protocol delegate that would make a ViewController implement label control initialization methods the right way of doing this?

EDIT:
How do I reuse the custom UIView so later when the labels style changes, I don't have to change looks on each of them separatly, but to have some sort o template that's going to be used every time the custom UIView is used

I'll put the **answer** here for anyone who'd have the same question:

You should use a custom UIView to control setting the labels (check the answer below) together with a .xib file which will define a template for the looks of the label.
If you're interested about UIView and .xib files check out this:
[How to use a xib and a UIView subclass together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071738/how-to-use-a-xib-and-a-uiview-subclass-together)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: More detail is needed.  What's so custom about the label?

Comment: Nothing really that custom. It always has two normal labels with a certain position and looks. I'm just not sure if it's not going to change globally. Changing each view by hand would be a pain...

Comment: Your question is still far from clear.  Besides the text on the label, what, specifically do you want to change about these labels?

Comment: The positioning of the labels on each of the custom UIViews, for example

Comment: Ok, I think the .xib file is what I needed. Thanks nhgrif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a delegate relationship to simply set a pair of text labels.  If you want to do a `UIView` subclass for a view with two labels, and simply add this view to your view controllers, then in your view subclass, right a method that would be similar to `UILabel setText:` method.  It just needs to take two arguments.

So if `mainLabel` and `subLabel` are `UILabel` properties on your `UIView` subclass's `.m` file, you might do something like this:

In the `UIView` subclass's `.h` file:

```
@interface DoubleLabelView

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *mainText;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *subText;

- (void)setText:(NSString*)mainText subText:(NSString*)subText;

@end
```

And then in the `.m` file:

```
@interface DoubleLabelView()

@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *mainLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *subLabel;

@end

@implementation DoubleLabelView

- (void)setText:(NSString*)mainText subText:(NSString*)subText {
    self.mainText = mainText;
    self.subText = subText;
}

- (void)setMainText:(NSString*)mainText {
    _mainText = mainText;
    self.mainLabel.text = mainText;
}

- (void)setSubText:(NSString*)subText {
    _subText = subText;
    self.subLabel.text = subText;
}
```

---

If the positions of the labels on the custom view are constant, I'd recommend just using a `.xib` file to set up exactly how you want the custom view to look.  And I might add a custom factory method that takes the `manText` and `subText` arguments and calls `setText:subText:` right then and there.

If you're subclassing `UIView`, the more code specific to the view you can contain within the subclass, the better.

---

In the same way I've added methods to the `UIView` to allow you to change the `mainText`, `subText`, or both at the same time in a single method call, you can continue to add methods such as this to change properties of your `UIView`.

If you want to reposition your labels, consider adding a pair of `CGPoint` properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGPoint mainLabelPosition;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGPoint subLabelPosition;

- (void)setPosition:(CGPoint)mainPosition subPosition:(CGPoint)subPosition;
```

And write methods for these similar to the ones I showed you for changing the text.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but how do I put this thing on all viewcontrollers in such way that I don't have to change each of them later when style changes?

Comment: Change what?  Again, as I commented to the original question, I need a whole lot more detail.  You're being extremely vague.

Comment: I asked about this in a comment to your comment :) I'll edit the question

Comment: You've never specified exactly what you want to change.  A label is a UI element that is only on a single view.  It shouldn't be changed by anything other than the view controller controlling the view it is on.  There should be nothing global about a UI element.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of UIView as below,

**CustomView.h file**

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@property UILabel *mainLabel;
@property UILabel *subLabel;

-(void)showMainLabelWithText:(NSString *)text;
-(void)showSubLabel:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

**CustomView.m file**

```
@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)showMainLabelWithText:(NSString *)text{
    self.mainLabel =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.mainLabel.text =text;
    [self addSubview:self.mainLabel];
}
-(void)showSubLabel:(NSString *)text{
    self.subLabel =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.subLabel.text =text;
    [self addSubview:self.subLabel];
}
```

Comment: This will create two UILabels to use, that's cool, but what about layout? How can I automate this?

Comment: mainLabel and subLabel are public properties, just set their frame like instance.mainLabel.frame =someFrame;